# Dialog themed activity wrap scrollview better

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, scrollview

I've got an activity, which is themed with Holo.Dialog (or plain old Dialog on older API levels), and contains a ScrollView as it's main layout, in case we encounter smaller screens that can't display all the content. My problem now is that the dialog is needing to scroll to see all the content, even when we have leftover vertical screen space, as seen below:

[image]

Here's the code for the ScrollView and it's one child, a LinearLayout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

What do I need to change to get this dialog to wrap more nicely? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the `maxHeight` and `minHeight` attributes?(they are something like that). I got told to do that for something similar, but never got around to trying it because my emulator is deathly slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to take the buttons out of the ScrollView and put them top level in a RelativeLayout. By putting the buttonbar first in the XML, aligned to parent bottom, and then setting the scrollView's layout_above to the buttonBar, I got the effect I was looking for